# How to gracefully shut down kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have tried gracefully removing a node from a Kubernetes cluster. But is there a way to gracefully shutdown the Kubernetes cluster instead of removing the nodes one at a time?

Comment: Frame challenge: _why_ do you want to shut it down gracefully? In my (admittedly limited) experience, k8s simply doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know if it's more 'graceful', it's certainly more convenient to:

```
nodes=$(kubectl get nodes -o name)

for node in ${nodes[@]}

do
    echo "==== Shut down $node ===="
    ssh $node sudo shutdown -h 1
done
```

[Source.](https://kubesphere.io/docs/v3.3/cluster-administration/shut-down-and-restart-cluster-gracefully/)